# How to add star rating in grid view with html and css?

Tags: html, css, jscript

I need to make a web page where students can rate teachers. On the web page I want to show cards dynamically which will contain name of the teacher and Star rating.
From other posts in stack overflow I have managed to get dynamic cards and star ratings on the page.
Now looking for help for 2 issues I am having.

1. How I can move my stars in center of the card and stars be responsive to the size of the card?
2. How I can have star radio buttons independent? Currently changing one changes value of other radio also.
   Please find my code below.

Thanks!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 //Prepare Element selectors
  var cssElem = $("#Dynam"), rowElem = $("#rows"), columnElem = $("#columns"), appElem = $("#app");
  var noItems = $(".item").length,defaultColumns = 4;
    
  //Init default state
  cssElem.html(".container .item {flex: 0 0 calc(" + (100 / defaultColumns) + "% - 1em);}");
  columnElem.val(defaultColumns);
  rowElem.val(Math.ceil(noItems / columnElem.val()));

  //Add listeners to change
  appElem.on("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
    noItems = $(".item").length;
    rowElem.val(Math.ceil(noItems / columnElem.val()));
  });
  columnElem.on("change", function() {
    rowElem.val(Math.ceil(noItems / columnElem.val()));
    cssElem.html(".container .item {flex: 0 0 calc(" + (100 / columnElem.val()) + "% - 1em);}");
  });
  rowElem.on("change", function() {
    columnElem.val(Math.ceil(noItems / rowElem.val()));
    cssElem.html(".container .item {flex: 0 0 calc(" + (100 / columnElem.val()) + "% - 1em);}");
  });
});

const COLORS = ['#FE9', '#9AF', '#F9A', "#AFA", "#FA7"];

function addItem(container, template) {
  let color = COLORS[_.random(COLORS.length - 1)];
  let num = _.random(10000);
  let count = num;

  container.append(Mustache.render(template, {
    color,
    num,
    count
  }));
}

$(() => {
  const tmpl = $('#item_template').html()
  const container = $('#app');

  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    addItem(container, tmpl);
  }

  $('#add_el').click(() => {
    addItem(container, tmpl);
  })

  container.on('click', '.del_el', (e) => {
    $(e.target).closest('.item').remove();
  });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    // Check Radio-box
    $(".rating input:radio").attr("checked", false);

    $('.rating input').click(function () {
        $(".rating span").removeClass('checked');
        $(this).parent().addClass('checked');
    });

    $('input:radio').change(
      function(){
        var userRating = this.value;
        alert(userRating);
    }); 
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.container .item {
  min-height: 120px;
  margin: 0.25em 0.5em;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align:center
}

.rating {
    float:left;
    width:300px;
}
.rating span { float:right; position:relative; }
.rating span input {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    opacity:0;
}
.rating span label {
    display:inline-block;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    text-align:center;
    color:#FFF;
    background:#ccc;
    font-size:30px;
    margin-right:2px;
    line-height:30px;
    border-radius:50%;
    -webkit-border-radius:50%;
}
.rating span:hover ~ span label,
.rating span:hover label,
.rating span.checked label,
.rating span.checked ~ span label {
    background:#F90;
    color:#FFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mustache.js/2.3.0/mustache.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style id="Dynam"></style>
<button id="add_el">Add element</button> rows:
<input id="rows" /> columns:<input id="columns" />

<div id="app" class="container">
</div>

<template id="item_template">
  <div class="item" style="background: {{color}}">
    <p>{{ num }}</p>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rating">
    <span><input type="radio" name="raiting" id="str5" value="5"><label for="str5"></label></span>
    <span><input type="radio" name="raiting" id="str4" value="4"><label for="str4"></label></span>
    <span><input type="radio" name="raiting" id="str3" value="3"><label for="str3"></label></span>
    <span><input type="radio" name="raiting" id="str2" value="2"><label for="str2"></label></span>
    <span><input type="radio" name="raiting" id="str1" value="1"><label for="str1"></label></span>
</div>
    <p>
      <button class="del_el">Delete</button>
    </p>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you center your stars.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 //Prepare Element selectors
  var cssElem = $("#Dynam"), rowElem = $("#rows"), columnElem = $("#columns"), appElem = $("#app");
  var noItems = $(".item").length,defaultColumns = 4;
    
  //Init default state
  cssElem.html(".container .item {flex: 0 0 calc(" + (100 / defaultColumns) + "% - 1em);}");
  columnElem.val(defaultColumns);
  rowElem.val(Math.ceil(noItems / columnElem.val()));

  //Add listeners to change
  appElem.on("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
    noItems = $(".item").length;
    rowElem.val(Math.ceil(noItems / columnElem.val()));
  });
  columnElem.on("change", function() {
    rowElem.val(Math.ceil(noItems / columnElem.val()));
    cssElem.html(".container .item {flex: 0 0 calc(" + (100 / columnElem.val()) + "% - 1em);}");
  });
  rowElem.on("change", function() {
    columnElem.val(Math.ceil(noItems / rowElem.val()));
    cssElem.html(".container .item {flex: 0 0 calc(" + (100 / columnElem.val()) + "% - 1em);}");
  });
});

const COLORS = ['#FE9', '#9AF', '#F9A', "#AFA", "#FA7"];

function addItem(container, template) {
  let color = COLORS[_.random(COLORS.length - 1)];
  let num = _.random(10000);
  let count = num;

  container.append(Mustache.render(template, {
    color,
    num,
    count
  }));
}

$(() => {
  const tmpl = $('#item_template').html()
  const container = $('#app');

  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    addItem(container, tmpl);
  }

  $('#add_el').click(() => {
    addItem(container, tmpl);
  })

  container.on('click', '.del_el', (e) => {
    $(e.target).closest('.item').remove();
  });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    // Check Radio-box
    $(".rating input:radio").attr("checked", false);

    $('.rating input').click(function () {
        $(".rating span").removeClass('checked');
        $(this).parent().addClass('checked');
    });

    $('input:radio').change(
      function(){
        var userRating = this.value;
        alert(userRating);
    }); 
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.container .item {
  min-height: 120px;
  margin: 0.25em 0.5em;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align:center
}

.rating {
    display:flex;
    width:100%;
    justify-content: center;
}
.rating span { float:right; position:relative; }
.rating span input {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    opacity:0;
}
.rating span label {
    display:inline-block;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    text-align:center;
    color:#FFF;
    background:#ccc;
    font-size:30px;
    margin-right:2px;
    line-height:30px;
    border-radius:50%;
    -webkit-border-radius:50%;
}
.rating span:hover ~ span label,
.rating span:hover label,
.rating span.checked label,
.rating span.checked ~ span label {
    background:#F90;
    color:#FFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mustache.js/2.3.0/mustache.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style id="Dynam"></style>
<button id="add_el">Add element</button> rows:
<input id="rows" /> columns:<input id="columns" />

<div id="app" class="container">
</div>

<template id="item_template">
  <div class="item" style="background: {{color}}">
    <p>{{ num }}</p>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rating">
    <span><input type="radio" name="raiting" id="str5" value="5"><label for="str5"></label></span>
    <span><input type="radio" name="raiting" id="str4" value="4"><label for="str4"></label></span>
    <span><input type="radio" name="raiting" id="str3" value="3"><label for="str3"></label></span>
    <span><input type="radio" name="raiting" id="str2" value="2"><label for="str2"></label></span>
    <span><input type="radio" name="raiting" id="str1" value="1"><label for="str1"></label></span>
</div>
    <p>
      <button class="del_el">Delete</button>
    </p>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks that helps to center the stars.
Any idea for question 2? Probably need to have dynamic Id for radio buttons?

Comment: clicking on the stars, rating  now go from right to left how can we change so that it goes from left to right?